# Decomposition of measurable function by characteristic functions with given coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f : X \to [0, \infty]$ be measurable, and let  $\{r_k\}$ be any sequence
of positive numbers for which $r_k \to 0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty r_k=\infty$. Then there are measurable sets $\{A_k\}$ such that
$$f (x) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty r_k \chi_{A_k}(x)$$
for any $x\in X$.

I read real analysis Bruckner by myself. It is valuable for me to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a final answer. It is easy to prove for $f$ being the indicator function of a measurable set $A$. In this case, you can prove that there is $N \subset \mathbb{N}$ for which $\sum_{n \in N} r_n = 1$, then you can define $A_n$ as $A$ if $n \in N$ and as $\varnothing$ otherwise. The conditions on $r_k$ ensure that for every $y > 0$ you can find a subset $N_y$ with $\sum_{k \in N_y} r_k = y$. But I don't see a way to pass from indicator functions to measurable functions.

Comment: Define things recursively. We start with $g_0 \equiv 0$. If we have found $g_m$ and $A_m$ for $m < k$, define $A_k = \{ x : g_{k-1}(x) + r_k \leqslant f(x)\}$, and $g_k = g_{k-1} + r_k\chi_{A_k}$.